A question about producing a 4-D plot with respect to three variables
I have a question about creating a 4D plot in MATLAB, where three parameters are represented as $\lambda_2$ is on the x-axis, $\lambda_3$ is on the y-axis, and $\lambda_1$ is on the z-axis. Additionally, the color represents the NMI values as the fourth dimension.
Attached, you will find the plot I would like to reproduce it. Could someone provide the MATLAB code to create it?
enter image description here
Thank you in advance for your help!
I tried creating a 4D scatter plot in MATLAB to visualize the relationship between these three parameters ($\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$) and an output variable NMI. I expected to see a layered scatter plot where each layer corresponds to a different $\lambda_1$ value, with $\lambda_2$ on the x-axis, $\lambda_3$ on the y-axis, $\lambda_1$ on the z-axis, and colors representing NMI values. However, initially, I encountered issues with performing this plan.
This is the code I used:
lambda1 = [0, 1e-6, 1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3];  % Z-axis

lambda2 = [0, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000];  % X-axis

lambda3 = [0, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 2];  % Y-axis


NMI = rand(length(lambda3), length(lambda2), length(lambda1)); 

figure;

hold on;

colormap('turbo'); 

scatterSize = 50; % Size of scatter points

for i = 1:length(lambda1)

% Extract layer data
[L2, L3] = meshgrid(lambda2, lambda3);

layerNMI = NMI(i, :, :);

x = log10(L2(:)); % \lambda2 (log scale)

y = log10(L3(:)); % \lambda3 (log scale)

z = lambda1(i) * ones(size(x)); % \lambda1

c = layerNMI(:); % NMI values as colors

scatter3(x, y, z, scatterSize, c, 'filled');

end

xlabel('\lambda_3 (log_{10})');

ylabel('\lambda_2 (log_{10})');

zlabel('\lambda_1');

colorbar;

caxis([0, 1]); 

title('3D Parameter Grid with NMI');

grid on;

view(3);

hold off;


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@melvio, thanks. I edited my question and put the code I used. But I could not find a good solution for my problem.

When you define layerNMI layerNMI = NMI(i, :, :); indexing the first dimension does not make sense because lambda1 is the third dimension in NMI:NMI = rand(length(lambda3), length(lambda2), length(lambda1));.
To fix the code, change it to read layerNMI = NMI(:, :, i);
lambda1 = [0, 1e-6, 1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3];  % Z-axis
lambda2 = [0, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000];  % X-axis
lambda3 = [0, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 2];  % Y-axis
NMI = rand(length(lambda3), length(lambda2), length(lambda1)); 
figure;
hold on;
colormap('turbo'); 
scatterSize = 50; % Size of scatter points
for i = 1:length(lambda1)
% Extract layer data
[L2, L3] = meshgrid(lambda2, lambda3);
layerNMI = NMI(:, :, i);
x = log10(L2(:)); % \lambda2 (log scale)
y = log10(L3(:)); % \lambda3 (log scale)
z = lambda1(i) * ones(size(x)); % \lambda1
c = layerNMI(:); % NMI values as colors
scatter3(x, y, z, scatterSize, c, 'filled');
end
xlabel('\lambda_3 (log_{10})');
ylabel('\lambda_2 (log_{10})');
zlabel('\lambda_1');
colorbar;
caxis([0, 1]); 
title('3D Parameter Grid with NMI');
grid on;
view(3);
hold off;


